# Why is my code giving absurd ouputs that makes no sense?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

i am new to C and was writing a code that prints the max and min from a array of integers.
Ex:- Input is 1 2 3 4 5, then the output will be min=1+2+3+4=10 and max=2+3+4+5=14. My code is giving output 0 0 instead of 10 14. I just can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
        int len;
        int max=0,min=0;
        scanf("%d", &len);
        int arr[len];
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
            }
        int cpy;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
                    {
                        if(arr[i]>arr[j])
                            {
                                 cpy = arr[i+1];
                                 arr[i+1]=arr[i];
                                 arr[i]=cpy;
                            }
                    }
            }
        
        for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++)
            {
                min = min + arr[i];
                max = max + arr[i+1];
            }
        printf("%d %d", min, max);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the input be `5 1 2 3 4 5` since you read len first?

Comment: @PaulHankin yes i am doing that, i just didn't write it here. The output is still the same.

Comment: doesn't reproduce. `5 1 2 3 4 5` yields `10 14`  https://onlinegdb.com/MneUtmxcH

Comment: the code you gave works fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

In this part :

```
if(arr[i]>arr[j])
{
    cpy = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1]=arr[i];
    arr[i]=cpy;
 }
```

You compare i and j index , but swap i and i+1 indexes. In your case :

- 5  1 2 3 4 5 gives 14 10
- 5  5 4 3 2 1 gives 13 10

You also should be looping i < len - 1. Even if it works as j loop will not run for i = len - 1, it is always better to avoid unnecessary looping which could lead to undefined behavior.

You may have problem with the declaration of arr (I got error but it may depends on the compiler) . Try allocating it :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
…..
int *arr = calloc(len, sizeof (*arr));
```